# Custom image sizes only for thumbnails

Tags: thumbnails, images

I solve one problem, I use in template several different sizes of images (add_image_size), but I use them only for thumbnails, it is completely unnecessary to create these sizes for each image uploaded to WP, I have tens of thousands of images in media. Not sure how to solve this idea? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/crstauf/WordPress-FeaturedImage-SpecialImageSize

try this out; wrote it myself a long time ago. I do have an updated version, coming out soon. let me know if you've any questions.

as requested, relevant code for functions.php of your theme:

```
// `post_type` => array(width,height,crop)
$featimg_sizes = array(
    'post' => array(50,20,false)
);

add_action('wp_ajax_set-post-thumbnail','generate_featimg_size',1);
function generate_featimg_size() {
    global $featimg_sizes;

$thumbnail_id = intval( $_POST['thumbnail_id'] );
$type = get_post_type(intval( $_POST['post_id'] ));

if (!isset($thumbnail_id)) return;
if ('-1' == $thumbnail_id) return;
if (!array_key_exists($type,$featimg_sizes)) return;

$size = $featimg_sizes[$type];
if (!isset($size[0]) || !isset($size[1]) || empty($size[0]) || empty($size[1])) return;
if (!isset($size[2])) $size[2] = false; // set $crop if left blank to false

$meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($thumbnail_id);
$path = apply_filters('image_make_intermediate_size',get_attached_file($thumbnail_id));

if ($newsize = image_make_intermediate_size($path,$size[0],$size[1],$size[2])) {
    $backupsizes = get_post_meta($thumbnail_id,'_wp_attachment_backup_sizes',true);
    $meta['sizes']['ptfi_'.$type] = $backupsizes['ptfi_'.$type] = $newsize; // ptfi = post type featured image

    update_post_meta($thumbnail_id,'_wp_attachment_metadata',$meta);
    update_post_meta($thumbnail_id,'_wp_attachment_backup_sizes',$backupsizes);
}
}
`
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the most relevant code. External link can not be trusted not to disappear at some point.

Comment: posting code can not be trusted to remain relevant to the current WordPress version. what should be done?

Comment: Awesome Caleb, this is great solution and works well. Thank you.

Comment: @MichalPelech, do you mind voting up my answer? trying to gain some rep.

Comment: @Caleb I wanted to, but I do not have the required amount of reputation.

Comment: @MichalPelech do you need a plugin with more options, or is dimensions per post type enough?